# Is the Function interface missing a new() signature?

Tags: typescript

I have some generic code which looks like this:

```
interface IClass<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}

function someFactory<T>(a: IClass<T>): T {
    return new a();
}

class Foo { }

var f = someFactory(Foo);
```

and `f` is correctly inferred as `Foo`. The function also disallows non-newable types.

Also, the compiler allows the following and the type of `f` is `any`:

```
function Foo() { }

var f = new Foo();
```

So I would expect the following generic code to work:

```
interface IInstance<T> {
    constructor: IClass<T>;
}

function extractType<T>(a: IInstance<T>): IClass<T> {
    return a.constructor;
}

class Foo { }

var f = new Foo();
var t = extractType(f);
```

but I get this error on the `f` argument to extract type:

> Argument of type 'Foo' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IInstance<{}>'.

If I relax the typing:

```
function extractType<T extends Object>(a: T): IClass<T> {
    return a.constructor;
}

class Foo { }

var f = new Foo();
var t = extractType(f);
```

I get this error on `a.constructor`:

> Type 'Function' is not assignable to type 'IClass'.

Since a function is new'able, I would expect one those patterns to work. If I extend the Function interface with a `new()` signature, they both work:

```
interface Function {
    new (...args: any[]): any;
}
```

So, is `Function` missing a `new()` signature, or is there another way to express my intent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause here is that TypeScript doesn't actually add a `constructor` property to objects that are class instances.

The `constructor` property you used in `extractType` actually exists only because property access uses the *apparent type* of the operand, which adds the members of the global interface `Object` to the type.

Technically this code works, but is obviously not generalizable to all classes:

```
class Foo {
    'constructor': typeof Foo;
}

var f = new Foo();
var t = extractType(f); // t: IClass<Foo>
```

Fundamentally `extractType` cannot be written in a general fashion in TypeScript because there's not an exact 1:1 correspondence between constructor functions and object types. You might have something like this:

```
interface MyObjectType { /* ... */ }
var foo1: {
    new(): MyObjectType;
    xx: number;
};
var foo2: {
    new(): MyObjectType;
    yy: string;
};
var x = Math.random() > 0.5 ? new foo1() : new foo2(); // x: MyObjectType
var t = extraType(x); // t: typeof foo1, or t: typeof foo2?
```